Mixed integer optimization: what if X has to be a rounded multiple of a fixed value?
I am working on a Mosek project. The utility function is to maximize
u^{t} x 

where x is a vector of N
There is a tricky constraint: the first 3 items of X must be integer multiple of a constant \rho , e.g.
{\rho, \rho * 3 , \rho * 4 , x_3, x_4, ... x_n}

The closest thing I can find is :
https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/mio.html#fixed-set-of-values
in which we could enumerate all possible rounded multiples and put them in a set
However, as we could see, this approach does not take advantage of the fact that, the 'discrete set of values' is not random, but follows a pattern.
I am wondering if anyone here could have a better idea.
Thanks a lot

This is a minor variation of the examples in the link. Here's one way: Declare x_1 to be integer; constrain x_1 to be within whatever bounds you needs (such as nonnegative, or positive, or whatever you require). Then use x_1*rho in place of x_1 in the rest of your model (such as objective function ). Similarly for x_2, x_3. The easiest way to accomplish this may depend on the modeling environment you are implementing this in.

@MarkL.Stone You should make this an answer.

@prubin I'll let someone else have the honors. I don't feel like putting in the stylistic flourishes which seem to be required of answers.
